# Skeleton Smaller Than Mesh

Tags: armature

Skeleton issue on blender. I know this has something to do with Blender since I've opened it with the 3D Viewer on Windows and it works fine. I've messed around with the FBX options in Blender but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.